# Textfield Validation in Java using LostFocus event

Tags: java, regex, swing, validation, lostfocus

I am validating two textfields using LostFocus event as follows:

```
textRegNo.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {            
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            regNo1=textRegNo.getText();
            Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$");
            Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(regNo1);

            if (!matcher1.find()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Vehicle No!!!\n Vehicle no should be of the form MH 03 KS 2131!!");
            }                           
        }
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        };
    }); 


textMobNo.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {            
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mobNo1=textMobNo.getText();
            Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^[789]\\d{9}$");
            Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(mobNo1);

            System.out.println("'"+mobNo1+"'");
            if (!matcher2.find()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone no must be a 10 digit number!!");
            }                           
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        };
    });
```

My problem is that when i lose focus on 1st textfield and move that focus to the 2nd text filed error message gets printed for both the fields(MESSAGE inside IF block under both lostfocus event.)
When i give wrong input into 1st textfield and move focus to 2nd field it should only print the error message for 1st text field. But its printing error for both.

1st textfield is textRegNo
2nd textfield is textMobNo

Comment: Try using [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) instead of focus listener for validating fields...

Comment: The symptom of the problem revolves around this process.  `textMobNo` gains focus, which causes `textRegNo` to lose focus, `textRegNo` is validated and found to be invalid, `textRegNo` now displays an error message...`textMobNo` loses focus (because the dialog gained focus)

Comment: Can you suggest any solution for the thing you just explained? Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, use a `InputVerifer`, that's what they're there for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symptom of the problem revolves around this process.

1. `textMobNo` gains focus...
2. which causes `textRegNo` to lose focus...
3. `textRegNo` is validated and found to be invalid, `textRegNo` now displays an error message...
4. Focus is transferred to the dialog and...
5. `textMobNo` loses focus (because the dialog gained focus)

You should avoid using focus as a means to validate fields if you can and instead use an [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

**Simple example**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class TestInputVerifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInputVerifier();
    }

    public TestInputVerifier() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
            field.setInputVerifier(new RegExpInputVerifier("^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$"));
            add(field, gbc);

            field = new JTextField(20);
            field.setInputVerifier(new RegExpInputVerifier("^[789]\\d{9}$"));
            add(field, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class RegExpInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

        private String expression;

        public RegExpInputVerifier(String expression) {
            this.expression = expression;
        }

        public String getExpression() {
            return expression;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            boolean verified = false;
            if (input instanceof JTextComponent) {
                JTextComponent field = (JTextComponent) input;
                String regNo1 = field.getText();
                Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(expression);
                Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(regNo1);
            }
            return verified;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of InputVerifier using regex as in my code. I am willing to use anonymous class. I am not sure how to use regex in InputVerifier.

Comment: It's pretty simple.  You take the code from `focusLost` and put it in `verify` of a `InputVerifier`

Comment: So... we are using InputVerifier but the problem is that the moment you select another window the event is never triggered and therefore the field does not get verified in time. What can be done to prevent this? Could one somehow trigger the verification from a focusLost event? These events seem to always get triggered the moment one would select another window.

Comment: About the only thing you “can” try is a FocudListener to force the validation

Comment: @DeanStrydom The problem you're facing comes down to the fact that a change in window focus is only considered a "temporary" focus lost, this means that the input verify won't trigger.  The question is, why would you want it validated in this manner?  Why does the user NOT need to come back and continue their data entry or select some "action" button to "submit" the values?