# Java multiple message dialogs at the same time with focusLost event

Tags: java

The problem is that when i click on the surname field when the name field is empty both messages appear because the focus is lost even from surname when the message dialog appears. Is there anything i can do to make the program show the name message and the focus to stay on the name field?

I tried the .requestFocus() but it didn't work.

```java
    private void NameFieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    
            if (NameField.getText().equals('smth')) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please put a name!","Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
    }                                                    
    private void SurnameFieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       
            if (SurnameField.getText().equals("smth")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please put a surname!","Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in the **NameFieldFocusLost** event: `if (NameField.getText().equals('smth')) {` doesn't fly. The **equals()** method requires a String: `if (NameField.getText().equals("smth")) {` or better yet...since you want to ensure a name is actually provided:

`if (NameField.getText().trim().equals("")) {`

There must be something we're not being shown. I don't understand why both MessageBoxes would be displaying when focus is taken away from the nameFieldFocusLost event. This shouldn't happen unless you have code somewhere moving focus around **especially before your form is actually visible**. The **requestFocus()** method should work as well and should be called directly **after** you display the MessageBox, for example:

```
private void nameFieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    
    if (nameField.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please put a name!","Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        nameField.setText("");      // Clear the JTextField in case a white-space was placed there.
        nameField.requestFocus();   // Force focus back onto the JTextField.
    }
}
```

If you are moving focus to a JTextField **before the parent container is visible** (Form / JDialog) then you could possibly experience your particular problem.

> **EDIT:**

Ahhh...I see the problem, thank you for the comment. Here are a few ways you can get around this dilemma:

1. Add a condition within the **focusLost** event for the next
   JTextField to be in focus which will force an exit of that event
   should the validation of the previously focused JTextField fail.

   In your case you have a First Name text field and a Last Name text
   field. In the focusLost event for the Last Name field you would have
   the very first line of code being:

   ```
   if (nameField.getText().trim().equals("")) { return; }
   ```

   This way the remaining event code doesn't get run in the Surname
   Lost Focus event unless validation for Name field is successful. The
   entire Surname event code may look like this:

   ```
   private void surnameFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {       
       if (nameField.getText().trim().equals("")) { return; }
       if (surnameField.getText().trim().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please put a last name!","Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           surnameField.setText("");      // Clear the JTextField in case a white-space was placed there.
           surnameField.requestFocus();   // Force focus back onto the JTextField.
       }
   }
   ```
2. An other way would be to utilize the [InputVerifier
   Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).
   There is good example of its use in [this SO
   post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18652782/4725875).
3. Don't use the JTextField's Focus Events at all. If there is a button
   that will be selected to further processing with the inputted data
   then check the validation for all your JTextFields there (in the button's actionPerformed event) and force a
   focus upon the field that fails (`nameField.requestFocus();`) for proper input.

Comment: The problem is when i move from the name field to the surname field leaving the name field empty both of the error messages pop up because the surname loses focus and so the message appears. so the logic that the program goes is : 1-move from name field to surname field and leave the name field empty. 2-namefield loses focus and the event runs but the surname had focus and lost it too after the error 3- name field error pops up and after the surname error too. the only code is on the focus lost event @DevilsHnd